# Definition of exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

What is a good definition of exponential equation? I'm trying to brush up on my calculus with Larson's "Calculus", and in one of the exercises he says that e^0=1 is an exponential equation. Shouldn't an equation contain at least one variable?

Comment: It's an equation as soon as it has an "$=$" sign. My guess is the author is calling it an exponential equation because it has an exponent. (I think it's as simple as that?)

Comment: an equation is a relation between two mathematical objects (generally numbers). In algebra normally the numbers are quantities, and the = sign tells that the quantities are the same. So the equation is the relation between two quantities that states that both quantities are the same.

Comment: When two things are linked with $=$, we call it as equation...

Comment: A more appropiate representation would be $e^0 \equiv 1$, where $\equiv$ is the identity sign.